# difficulty with for loops and appending in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I need to write a for loop for the following process:

```
elements = [ 
            [ "a", ['aft','fwd','starboard']],
            [ "b", ['plastic','metal','wood']]
            ]

query1 = []
query2 = []
temp1 = []
temp2 = []
final = []

for keyword in elements[0][1]:
   a = do_something.search(keyword)
   query1.append(a)

temp1.append(elements[0][0])
temp1.append(query1)


for keyword in elements[1][1]:
    a = do_something.search(keyword)
    query2.append(a)

temp2.append(elements[1][0])
temp2.append(query2)

final.append(temp1)
final.append(temp2)
```

where do_something is a SQL query. The expected answer is something of the following:

```
final = [['a', [['result1','result2','result3'],['result4','result5']]],
        ['b', [['resultA','resultB']]]]
```

where results 1-5 are returned SQL queries associated with value 'a' and values A and B are returned SQL queries associated with value 'b'

My attempt:

```
query = []
temp = []
final = []


for i in range(0,len(elements)):
    for keyword in elements[i][1]:
       a = do_something.search(keyword)
       query.append(a)

 temp.append(elements[i][0])
 temp.append(query)
 final.append(temp)
```

but I seem to be over appending and I can't figure out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have condensed it ok you just aren't using clean containers

I would personally scope them in the loop :

```
#query = []
#temp = []
final = []


for i in range(0,len(elements)):
    temp = []
    query = [] # use an empty list 
    for keyword in elements[i][1]:
       a = do_something.search(keyword)
       query.append(a)

    temp.append(elements[i][0]) # before the temp still contained first iteration data. 
    temp.append(query)
    final.append(temp)
```